# Supporting QHD on Android Market

Tags: android

Using a Motorola Atrix 4G, it is not able to download the application I published and install on a phone. The suggested answer is to do this

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

but in my manifest it's like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Will changing my manifest to the above suggested answer cause any quirks because I want the minimum sdk to be at least a 2.1-update(which is "7")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got it working. The solution is to turn off the copyright protection. Since the app uploaded was free, it would not affect the application at all, but if it is a paid app, you will have to look into licensing as copyright will be deprecated in the future.

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

So apparently the problem had nothing to do with the display, but because the phone was rooted and Google Market did not allow an application that is rooted to install a copyright application.

Answer (score 0):

Motorola Atrix 4G in theory has Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) which is SDK level 9. So if you have minSdkVersion="7" and android:targetSdkVersion="9" it should work on this phone. Why would it not work?

Using a lower SDK level will give you problems but only if you use specific APIs from newer levels. If you rebuild your app with a lower API and it doesn't fail compiling, then you should be OK. (Unless you use reflection or some weird thing.)

Emmanuel