# Can not download my app from Android market

Tags: android, google-play

Recently I uploaded my app to Android market (a paid app).
But when I trying to download my app from Android market it keep said "This item isn't compatible with your device" and the download button isn't show up.
I don't know what's going wrong with the .apk I uploaded to the market.
The app works just find on my phone when I am developing it.

Could anyone help me to check does the "download/buy" button show up on your phone

Here is the link to my app:
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.buffpuffer.android.widgets

thanks a lot.

Comment: Modify the manifest and insure that it supports your platform version.

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to my question in this link [Supporting QHD on Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815668/supporting-qhd-on-android-market/7883765#7883765)

The problem I had was with the copyright protection.